# C# - Find all matches in worksheet using Excel

Tags: c#, excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfoQN.png)

I would like to find all "NC2" mathces in this worksheet (later the B column values).

I tried with range.find but I got back only one result.

How can I read out these cells? (Which contains NC2)

Answer (score 0):

what I would do is do a data -> filter to get all the cells.

if it helps, conditional formatting would also help to visually find all the cells containing NC2.

Comment: I don't know how can I do this. (Autofilter, foreach, list didn't work.)

Comment: not auto filter... go to data tab, there's a filter button. click on it. it will show an arrow at the header row. click on that arrow and all will be filtered. :D